# Java - file writing - access denied

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to write a file from my Java application but I can't write it anywhere but inside the app directory. I'm using Windows 10. I tried starting Eclipse as admin and tried packaging the runnable Jar file using Launch4j, getting the same error.
Any ideas how to write a file to a user-defined directory?

I'm using the PdfWriter package, which is instantiated with a Java FileOutputStream:

```
Document document = new Document();      
var writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(directory));
                document.open();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read [ask]. Then [edit] your question to follow the suggestions made there, including creating a [mcve]. Keep it as simple as possible. For example, start with a hard coded directory string. Then when you have that working use a variable instead. Then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide a snippet of your actual code to detect the problem in your approach. But if you only need a way to write a simple file take this (with java 8)

```
//Get the file reference
Path path = Paths.get("c:/output.txt");
 
//Use try-with-resource to get auto-closeable writer instance
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) 
{
    writer.write("Hello World !!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your source code for a better answer, but here is an example of working write to file function.

```
 void writeToFile(String input) throws IOException{
            File file = new File("C:\\YourDirectory\\FileName.txt");
            if (!file.getParentFile().mkdirs())
                    throw new IOException("Unable to create " + file.getParentFile());
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
            try{
                    out.append(input);
                    out.newLine();
            } finally {
            

    out.close();
        } 
}
```

Comment: Ok I solved the problem, it was only a small detail that I haven't considered.

Comment: @Maxim update your question with that detail to help others with the same problem in the future.